# Angular: Translated Option in HTML-Select is saved instead of original string

Tags: angular

I am using `Angular` and use the pipe-keyword `translate` in order to display multiple options in a `HTML-Select`. This is working just fine but there is a problem I am facing right now. I thought that the translation would only be for display purposes but now when a user selects one of the options the string that is saved to an attribute by using `ngModel` is always the translated version instead of the original string. Here is my HTML:

```
<select
  class="form-control"
  [(ngModel)]="person.gender"
  name="gender"
>
  <option *ngFor="let gender of genders">
    {{ gender | translate }}
  </option>
</select>
```

My original strings are `["M","W","D"]`. Translated they are `["Male","Female","Non-Binary"]` and `["Mann","Frau","Divers"]`.

Expectation:

```
//English
Display: "Male"
Value: "M"

// German
Display: "Mann"
Value : "M"
```

Reality:

```
// English
Display: "Male"
Value : "Male"

// German
Display: "Mann"
Value : "Mann"
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I need my original strings in order to persist data across the different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `[ngValue]="gender"` solved my problem:

```
<option *ngFor="let gender of genders" [ngValue]="gender">
```

Answer (score 0):

The two-way binding [(ngModel)] is causing that. You must use the (value) attribute to save the value instead of using two-way binding.

```html
    [value] = "person.gender"
```

Comment: Hmm does not seem to work. If I do it like you suggested I have an empty string since the value is not set for some reason.

Comment: sorry, it should be [value] instead of (value). Editing the answer